# netstat -o timer value "probe"

Tags: linux, networking, sockets, netstat

A bit of background on the scenario.
I have a distributed application running on RH6.5 that uses JMS (OpenMQ 4.5.2) to send messages between hosts.
One host (Host A) receives information from network elements such as routers and switches and relays that information to another host (Host B) for processing. JMS is running on Host B.
These messages flowing through JMS average at around 100 messages per second and can have spikes of several hundreds messages without any issues.

Occasionaly, I observe that the message flow grinds to a halt, nothing reaches Host B, dispite Host A is still receiving data from the network at similar rates.  When this happens, the JMS process on Host B takes up all of the CPU.

Using netstat -o, I also noticed that the Recv-Q of the JMS socket on Host B side is very high:

```
Proto   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address   Foreign Address State       Timer
tcp     268439  0       HostB:9030      HostA:53712     ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

On Host A side, the Send-Q is also high:

```
Proto   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address   Foreign Address State       Timer  
tcp     0       68736   HostA:53712     HostB:9030      ESTABLISHED probe (17.25/0/0)
```

I also noticed the value "probe" in the timer. Searching the web I found little information about the meaning of this value.

So, the question is,
What does a timer value of "probe" mean and could that reflect some kind of problem reading from or writing to socket?